# Superfish Menu inside WordPress Queries

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming, superfish

I am using jQuery Superfish Menu inside my WordPress theme, where I have the following setup inside my sidebar.php file:

```
        <div id="sidebar">

        <ul id="themenu" class="sf-menu sf-vertical">

            <li><a href="index.html" class="topm currentMenu nosub">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about-us.html" class="topm nosub">About Us</a></li>
            <li>
                <a class="sf-with-ul topm" href="#">Instruments</a>
                <ul class="bullet">
                    <li><a href="guitars.html">Guitars</a></li>
                    <li><a href="drums.html">Drums</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
```

My question is, can I transform this code above to use some wp php function such as wp_list_pages() for both top level menu items as well as the sub-menu items under the parent menu item of "Instruments" ?

Just want to know whether there is a WordPress way of doing the Superfish menu and bringing in the correct a href values alongside each list item?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using WP3 and have you considered using the custom nav feature? Just a thought :-)

Comment: Hi @ILMV - yes I am using WP3 - am new to it and don't know much about custom nav feature. Really want to stick to my Superfish menu as I have spent alot of time manipulating it with regards to look and feel as well as hovering aspects.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a theme that supports it (take a look at the Twenty Ten) you can play with the custom nav feature, go to "Appearance > Menus", you'll be able to construct your own menu within the WP admin screen, there should be no reason why you cannot just apply Superfish to the generated menu.

You should learn more about the [new custom menu feature in WordPress 3](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-navigation-menus-in-wordpress-3-0-themes/) and then apply Superfish to that output, any modifications to your menu from within WordPress will (read: should, if setup correctly) immediately work with Superfish.